# How can we approximate a patch by $r_{u}$,$r_{v},$\Delta u$,$\Delta v$

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

I am having the problem understanding the fact that the area of the patch can be approximated by$$|(\Delta u r_{u})\times (\Delta v r_{v})=|r_{u}\times r_{v}| \Delta u \Delta v$$[image]
 I don't understand how this came to be? won't the magnitude of $r_{u}$ or $r_{v}$ affect the approximation. I think it should be divided by its magnitudes? I am confused...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is what you want, but the [area of a parallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram) ABCD is given by 
$$
||\vec{AB}\times \vec{AD} ||
$$
Therefore, given a surface $S$ with parametrization
$$
\vec{r}(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)),\quad (u,v)\in D
$$
$
||\vec{r}_u\times \vec{r}_v||
$
is an infinitisemal area of $S$ around the point $\vec{r}(u,v)$. To obtain the area of the whole surface, you need to sum these small areas over all points of $D$, that is
$$
A(S)=\iint_D ||\vec{r}_u\times \vec{r}_v||\; dudv
$$

Another way of looking at it is by considering the one dimensional case. Instead of dealing with a surface, consider a curve $C$ with parametrization 
$$
\vec{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t)),\quad t\in [a,b]
$$
As one knows, the length of this curve equals
$$
L( C)= \int_a^b ||\vec{r}'(t)||\; dt,
$$
or, to use the same notations as before:
$$
L( C)= \int_a^b ||\vec{r}_t||\; dt.
$$
See how the structure of the formula is the same?